# open new tab with modal and redirect the old page in laravel project

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

i'm try to use a tag in my laravel project to open new tab with modal and redirect the old tab to another page

i try many solution to this problem and i don't get and result
one of the solution is

```
  <a onclick="window.open('https://www.w3schools.com');" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Mymodal{{$question->id}}">Open Modal</a>
```

its open new tab with the link but i need to stay in the page with the modal

one of the solution i use this in my view

```
<a href="{{route('mypage,$question->id')}}" target="_blank" onclick="location.replace('https://www.w3schools.com');"></a>
```

and i  add new function in the controller to open the page with jquery code to load th modal

```
<script>
     $(window).load(function(){        
       $('#Mymodal{{$question->id}}').modal('show');

        }); 
</script>
```

i still no able to redirect the old tab

Answer (score 0):

```
//html
<a id="click" href="www.abc.com" target="_blank"></a>  //link to open in new tab


//script
{
  $("#click").click();
  window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com"); // link to redirect the current tab
}
```